# Unlock root disk with TPM2 on Impish Indri

Tags: systemd, initramfs, cryptsetup, 21.10, tpm

Background:
Using the information in the manpages:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/systemd-cryptenroll.1.html

I have successfully added a TPM2.0 key to the LUKS disk with the command: `systemd-cryptenroll --tpm2-device=auto /dev/sda3`

However I cannot figure out how to configure the `/etc/crypttab` to enable automatic unlocking at boot.
I have tried to look into the information in the man pages: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man5/crypttab.5.html

Question:
How do I configure the `/etc/crypttab` and regenerate the `initramfs` to support TPM2 unlock at boot for the root disk with password fallback?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on 22.04, and (just) published a repository to help anyone else who wants to get TPM2 to automatically decrypt their disk on boot.

https://github.com/wmcelderry/systemd_with_tpm2

It's for people who already know what LUKS is, what cryptenroll does and how to follow the guide on Arch wiki and apply what they have documented well (thanks guys!) to what you want to get working in Ubunutu.

So, it's not easy to use, but it does make it a little easier to get going than working without it, and ultimately, it gives clues about what I have done to get it working if you're struggling.

There is a light at the end of the tunnel...

Comment: This is a great contribution. I tested McElderry patches (the two patches and the initramfs hook function) on Ubuntu 22.04 and can confirm that this worked flawlessly, kudos to W McElderry for the effort to get this to work. SystemD CryptEnroll works a LOT faster than clevis and opens the LUKS root fs in a cuple of seconds (whereas clevis adds a good 20+ seconds to the boot time). I hope ubuntu folks will pick this up and include it in future Ubuntu versions, so we won't need to do this low level tweaking in the future

Comment: I forgot to say, I did not run the full script of McEdlerry because systemd-cryptenroll in 22.04 as of today (22.04.2) supports TPM, there is no need to rebuild it. I just used the two patches and the initram hook

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in Arch, reading the various wiki pages.  This may have some applicability (though I'm about to do the same thing again in Ubuntu)

Details of the crypttab are here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Trusted_Platform_Module#Data-at-rest_encryption_with_LUKS

but the method to refresh the initramfs will be different, perhaps:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this:

I believe Impish Indri is not capable of this (not at the current time/out of the box, but maybe with a subsequent update)

Systemd version is v248 (248.3-1ubuntu8) from installation media or with latest updates: systemd 248 (248.3-1ubuntu8.2)

It looks to me like support for decryption with TPM was introduced in systemd 249, based on this man page which indicates that it (A) supports a TPM and (B) is supplied by systemd v249 [at the time of writing time]:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crypttab.5.html

Looking in to systemd-cryptsetup brought me to a useful script which indicates how to setup and test the system the OP and I desire:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/c40671ba16805909925c70a9708b4b80031834cb/man/tpm2-crypttab.sh

This does not work on Systemd V248, so I expect that v249 is the first it works with.

I'm downloading and testing the daily Jammy release to see if this will work in 22.04 and intend to report back.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My latest answer:  This doesn't yet work in Ubuntu as systemd-cryptsetup doesn't seem to support TPM2 devices.

I've now tested this in the daily build of 22.04 (Jammy) - it does include Systemd v249, but it still doesn't work.

Having dug and dug and dug, I now suspect that this is a build option that is not being enabled.

This could mean that v248 could have worked if the option were enabled (I cannot recall the error message)

Details of the issue follow...

The error message I see is 'TPM2 support not available.', which seems to come from:
[Line 61 or 78 of this header file](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/c40671ba16805909925c70a9708b4b80031834cb/src/cryptsetup/cryptsetup-tpm2.h#L61)

Which is controlled by:

[#if HAVE_TPM2](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/c40671ba16805909925c70a9708b4b80031834cb/src/cryptsetup/cryptsetup-tpm2.h#L10)

So I guess that hasn't been enabled at build time, for whatever reason.

I'm going to try and make contact with someone who may be able to shed light on this.  I may also try and build from source and see if I can successfully enable that option and resolve the issue.

Comment: I've posted to Launchpad to ask for more information:https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+question/700892